# Can I use .map() and spread operator for render a div in React hooks?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to render products array using a map, but when I try to use the spread operator to pass map data to child component, I get this error: `Parsing error: Unexpected token ...`. Do you know what is the reason?

This is my code:

```
<div className="products">
  {products &&
    products?.products?.map((data) => (
      <div key={data.id}>
        <Item data={...data} />
      </div>
    ))}
</div>
```

Comment: Expressions in JSX are embedded in `{...}`, so if you want to spread the `data` object into the `data` prop it needs to be `data={{...data}}`. The inner `{...data}` being the spread of the `data` object and the outer pair just being standard JSX syntax.

Comment: Note that there's probably no good reason to spread here (as `Item` should not be mutating its props), so you could just be doing `data={data}`.

Comment: @RobinZigmond that just copies the `data` object, to spread each key/value pair as props you want `<Item {...data} />`

Comment: @Mulan sure that will spread all props but looking at the OP it seems they want to pass some specific object data to a prop called `data`. Your version will populate a bunch of props, depending on the content of the `data` object. Maybe that is what they want, it's totally not clear.

Comment: @RobinZigmond that's not the way i understand the question. it looks to me that they want `Item` to get a prop/value for each key/value of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do it is:

```
<Item {...data} />
```